# What should be the public object when writing a script that manipulates every prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game where I have a few moving blocks which the player can slow, these blocks all come from a singular prefab and I must also mention that the player has the ability to slow all blocks at a time.

**What I have tried**

To accomplish this I added a script to my game manager, which accepts a game object then accesses the script that controls the movement of the game objects. After that I go and I drag the prefab(from projectview)  of all my movingblocks and assign it as the public variable game objects in the script i wrote.

**Problem**

Sadly, this does not work, however, if I drag a single moving platform from hierarchy view into the public game object on the game object the manipulation (me slowing that object ) works.
Now, I am aware that I can attach a script to all the moving platforms, but i did not want to do this because  that script slows other items which has nothing to do with the moving platforms and I just wanted to have one single script handling the slowing, not having to write a second script to slow another type of game object.

So , any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could have a script on the prefab which decides how fast the object moves.

That script could then have a static variable which is the speed.

When a variable is static,it is shared by all users of that script.

You could then have the player set this variable through a static method and thus as it is a variable shared by all of the prefabs they are all affected.

```
public class BlockScript : MonoBehaviour{

    public static float speed= 1 f;

    public static void SetBlockSpeed(float value){
        speed = value;
    }

    void Update (){
         //Use speed
    }
}
```